# How to hide one field when the user enter data in another field .NET MVC 4 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I had one field something like Holiday such that is given below,

```
 [StringLength(50)]
 [DisplayName(Constants.DisplayName.HolidayDay)]
 public virtual string HolidayDay { get; set; }
```

And

```
 public virtual enumHolidayDay enumHolidayDay
 {
      get
      {
            return (enumHolidayDay)Enum.Parse(typeof(enumHolidayDay), HolidayDay);
      }
      set
      {
            HolidayDay = value.ToString();
      }
 }
```

And

```
public enum enumHolidayDay
{
    [Description("Saturday")]
    saturday = 1,

    [Description("Sunday")]
    sunday = 2,
}
```

And my Holiday.cshtml file is following

```
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="" class="control-label">
                Set Holiday For </label><br />
                     @Html.EnumCheckBoxFor(m => m.enumHolidayDay)
            </div>
        </div>
       <br/>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="" class="control-label">
                    Day</label><br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HolidayDay, new { @class = "form-control"  
                                              }).DisableIf(() => Model.IsReadOnly == true)
            </div>
        </div>
```

On my screen there are two checkboxes named Saturday and another one is Sunday. And one textbox named Day, But user can enter data in either one of it. One is mandatory. How to handle them, i.e. How to disable the Day field when the user click the any checkbox. And the Holiday field only used to these controls. In which event i have to handle it without using scripts and what are the code i need to add for this. Can anyone please help to find the solution...

Comment: why don't you make use of jQuery?

Comment: Use javascript/jQuery to toggle control's visibility

Comment: Not like that. If you can help me then please help me. And I thought that there is a possibility to make it easily without using JQuery because this is MVC 4 Razor right that's why

Comment: its pretty easy with jquery, check bellow code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check bellow code

**With jQUery**

```js
$('#checkboxId').click(function () {
    $("#txtholidy").toggle(!this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' id="checkboxId" checked='checked'>Sunday
</br></br><input type='textbox' id="txtholidy" style='display:none' >
```

***Updated***
**Without jQUery**

```js
function toggleControl()
{

  if(document.getElementById("checkboxId").checked == true)
    {
  document.getElementById("txtholidy").style.visibility="hidden";
      }
else
  {
  document.getElementById("txtholidy").style.visibility="visible";
  }
  }
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id="checkboxId" checked='checked' onClick="toggleControl()">Sunday
</br></br><input type='textbox' id="txtholidy" style="visibility:hidden" >
```

Comment: JQuery is not supporting so please any other solution with javascript?

Comment: check updated code without jQuery, purely on JavaScript