# Adding fields to form based on a value in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a drop down in my view. Say the selected value is 1, I want to show the next field as textbox.
@f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(model => model.Parameter)

If the selected value is 2, then i need it as a dropdown with a list of values.
@f.FormGroup().DropDownListFor(model => model.Parameter, Model.ForumList)

If the selected value is 3, then i need to hide the parameter.

What is the best way to acheive this?

Thanks in advance,
Vanitha.

Comment: You should use JavaScript/jQuery and add a listener on the `change` event of your drop down list. Based on the value, add the appropriate input control.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26668131/1107638

Check this answer, its toggling control's visibility on checkbox checked event, you can do same thing on dropdown's value changed event.

Comment: I have already done that using jquery and ajax. I wanted to know is there a way of doing it with MVC 5. With partials and so on... since i am new to MVC. Thanks @Andrei V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a function inside javascript that should be called onChange event of your dropdownlist. Pass the value of dropdown to that on change function and use if condition to decide which element to show, for this purpose you can keep a div and append elements inside it on runtime

```
function myfunc(dropValue)

{
if(dropValue==1)
document.getElementbyId('yourdiv').innerHtml=//the html for your element in ''
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kayani. I have it using jquery.

Comment: if you found the answer useful please mark it as correct in order to help others

Comment: I did this using jquery and ajax.